# Real relation between InnoDB secondary index and primary index

Tags: mysql, innodb

For table t:

```
mysql> show create table t\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: t
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `t` (
  `a` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `b` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`a`),
  KEY `b` (`b`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

```
mysql> select * from t;
+---+------+------+
| a | b    | c    |
+---+------+------+
| 1 |    3 |    3 |
| 2 |    2 |    4 |
| 3 |    3 |    4 |
| 4 |    5 |    2 |
+---+------+------+
```

there are some rows with the same column b value, for `select * from t where b = 3`, how innodb found all primary keys for secondary index of b = 3?
And how the leaf node of secondary index of b look like?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that the B-tree for a secondary index is organized by both the indexed column and the primary key. It's as if every secondary index has the `id` column appended to it.

For example:

| id | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 'a' |
| 2 | 12 | 'b' |
| 3 | 24 | 'c' |
| 4 | 12 | 'd' |

Suppose `id` is the primary key and `x` is indexed as a secondary key.  The real secondary key is `(x, id)`.

The leaf nodes will therefore be:

```
(12, 1)
(12, 2)
(12, 4)
```

In this way the leaf nodes always include the primary key value as well.

Looking up a row by its secondary index therefore requires two searches in B-trees. The first to search the secondary index B-tree, which yields one or more leaf nodes with distinct primary key values. Then the primary key values are used to search the primary key B-tree (the clustered index), which yields exactly one leaf node for each primary key value, and in that node is found all the columns, including both indexed and non-indexed columns.

If you're interested in a great deal more detail, I recommend Jeremy Cole's series of blog posts: https://blog.jcole.us/innodb/

Comment: Does it actually have a "list of PK values"?  I interpret that to mean your example has 2 "rows" in the Index's BTree.  Or is it effectively a BTree with two columns: (x,id) and a full 4 rows?

Comment: Good point, I may have misinterpreted Jeremy's page. I have rewritten the answer above.